# My model.fit and model.evaluate are not working properly and I am getting an error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
train_x = train['text']
valid_x = valid["text"]
train_y = train["label"]
valid_y = valid["label"]
train_y = train_y.values.reshape(-1,1)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit_transform(train_x)

x_train_count = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_x)

x_valid_count = vectorizer.fit_transform(valid_x)

x_test_count  = vectorizer.fit_transform(test["text"])

model = tf.keras.Sequential() 

model.add(Dense(50,input_dim=x_train_count.shape[1], kernel_initializer="uniform", activation="relu")) 
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer="uniform", activation="sigmoid")) 
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
# # Fit the model
history = model.fit(x_train_count, train_y, validation_data=(x_valid_count,valid_y), epochs=3, batch_size=128)

loss, acc = model.evaluate(x_test_count, test["label"], verbose=0)
```

## Error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-be49478b4c50> in <module>
         71 model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
         72 # # Fit the model
    ---> 73 history = model.fit(x_train_count, train_y, validation_data=(x_valid_count,valid_y), epochs=3, batch_size=128)
         74 
         75 loss, acc = model.evaluate(x_test_count, test["label"], verbose=0)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1048          training_utils.RespectCompiledTrainableState(self):
   1049       # Creates a `tf.data.Dataset` and handles batch and epoch iteration.
-> 1050       data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(
   1051           x=x,
   1052           y=y,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution)
   1098 
   1099     adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)
-> 1100     self._adapter = adapter_cls(
   1101         x,
   1102         y,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, sample_weight_modes, batch_size, steps, shuffle, **kwargs)
    564     inputs = pack_x_y_sample_weight(x, y, sample_weights)
    565 
--> 566     dataset = dataset_ops.DatasetV2.from_tensor_slices(inputs)
    567     num_samples = int(nest.flatten(x)[0].shape[0])
    568     if shuffle:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in from_tensor_slices(tensors)
    689       Dataset: A `Dataset`.
    690     """
--> 691     return TensorSliceDataset(tensors)
    692 
    693   class _GeneratorState(object):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, element)
   3155     element = structure.normalize_element(element)
   3156     batched_spec = structure.type_spec_from_value(element)
-> 3157     self._tensors = structure.to_batched_tensor_list(batched_spec, element)
   3158     self._structure = nest.map_structure(
   3159         lambda component_spec: component_spec._unbatch(), batched_spec)  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py in to_batched_tensor_list(element_spec, element)
    362   # pylint: disable=protected-access
    363   # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
--> 364   return _to_tensor_list_helper(
    365       lambda state, spec, component: state + spec._to_batched_tensor_list(
    366           component), element_spec, element)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py in _to_tensor_list_helper(encode_fn, element_spec, element)
    337     return encode_fn(state, spec, component)
    338 
--> 339   return functools.reduce(
    340       reduce_fn, zip(nest.flatten(element_spec), nest.flatten(element)), [])
    341 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py in reduce_fn(state, value)
    335   def reduce_fn(state, value):
    336     spec, component = value
--> 337     return encode_fn(state, spec, component)
    338 
    339   return functools.reduce(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py in <lambda>(state, spec, component)
    363   # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
    364   return _to_tensor_list_helper(
--> 365       lambda state, spec, component: state + spec._to_batched_tensor_list(
    366           component), element_spec, element)
    367 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\sparse_tensor.py in _to_batched_tensor_list(self, value)
    367       raise ValueError(
    368           "Unbatching a sparse tensor is only supported for rank >= 1")
--> 369     return [gen_sparse_ops.serialize_many_sparse(
    370         value.indices, value.values, value.dense_shape,
    371         out_type=dtypes.variant)]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_sparse_ops.py in serialize_many_sparse(sparse_indices, sparse_values, sparse_shape, out_type, name)
    493       return _result
    494     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
--> 495       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
    496     except _core._FallbackException:
    497       pass

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6860   message = e.message + (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
   6861   # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 6862   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   6863   # pylint: enable=protected-access
   6864 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)
```

InvalidArgumentError: indices[1] = [0,40295] is out of order. Many sparse ops require sorted indices.
Use `tf.sparse.reorder` to create a correctly ordered copy.

Comment: What if you try what the error massage suggests, something like  `tf.sparse.reorder(x_train_count)` ?

Comment: It won't work because it's not a sparsetensor object.

Answer (score 0):

The object returned by the *fit_transform()* and *fit()* methods of **TfIdfVectorizer** are compressed sparse row format matrix. So in order to convert them into dense matrix use `.toarray()` function.

Furthermore, you should fit your TfIdfVectorizer on the train_set only and then use it to transform your validation and test set without re-fitting it every time to avoid to use data from test set since it might introduce some **data leakage** and yield in too optimistic performances. Also, since the test and validation sets are usually small fitting a TfIdf solely on them will result in poor vectorization. Finally, and the Idf factor will be different for the same words in training, validation and test sets, and this is usually not desired.

For the mentioned reasons **I would suggest to fit the TfIdfVectorizer only on the training set** and then use the fitted vectorizer to transform the validation and test sets.

Here an example:

```
 vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
 x_train_count = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_x).toarray()
 x_valid_count = vectorizer.transform(valid_x).toarray()
 x_test_count  = vectorizer.transform(test["text"]).toarray()
```

If your data do not fit into memory, you could consider to iteratively convert to a dense matrix only one batch at the time. Here a function to create a batch generator from a sparse x_train matrix:

```
def sparse_matrix_batch_generator(X, y, batch_size=32):
    num_samples = np.shape(y)[0]
    shuffled_index = np.arange(num_samples)
    np.random.shuffle(shuffled_index)
    X =  X[shuffled_index, :]
    y =  y[shuffled_index]
    for n in range(num_samples//batch_size):
        batch_index = shuffled_index[n*batch_size:(n+1)*batch_size]
        X_batch = X[batch_index, :].todense()
        y_batch = y[batch_index]
        yield (X_batch, y_batch)
```

Comment: I tried that Davide, there's a memory error of 43 GB when you try this.
I also tried using toDense() as well, got the same memory error.

Comment: Thank you Davide, i'll try to make it work!